# Path based routing to respective EKS clusters for a React application

Tags: amazon-web-services, url-routing, amazon-cloudfront

I have multiple Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) clusters, each residing in a different Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) or even in different AWS accounts. Additionally, I own a domain called example.com. My goal is to route incoming requests to specific EKS clusters based on the subpath provided in the URL. Specifically, when a user visits example.com/customer1/, I want the request to be directed to the React application running in the ingress of the "customer1" EKS cluster. Similarly, example.com/customer2/ should be routed to the "customer2" EKS cluster's React application.
[image: Expected Architecture]

We attempted to use CloudFront as a reverse proxy with different origins and behaviors. We created a behavior for /customer1/* to direct all requests to the customer1 origin. However, this approach did not work as React was unable to load the static files and throwing 404. The application was searching for these files in the root directory (cloudfront.net) instead of the expected directory (cloudfront.net/customer1/).

Any help or suggestions on how to properly route requests to different EKS clusters based on URL context using CloudFront or using any other services would be greatly appreciated.